# Algorithm for Fragmenting String arithmetic expression with signed digit

Tags: string, algorithm

Good day, I was just wondering if there is a way to fragment a string of arithmetic expression like:

```
-2+-3+(4+5)
```

into **expected result**

```
-2 + -3 + ( 4 + 5 )
```

this given string is fragmented using whitespace, I intend to format this expression this way because I have to do something else with it delimited with a white space. That's not what I'm concerned right now, what I am aiming is that when I encounter a signed digit like the example above, instead of `-2 + -3 + ( 4 + 5 )` this, it will look like this `- 2 + - 3 + ( 4 + 5 )` .

Already know what caused this because I am replacing all signs with

```
<whitespace> <operator> <whitespace>
```

but how do I exclude the signed digits to not be fragmented like the expected result?

**NOTE:** 
Planning to be language independent because as of now, I don't know which one to use, the algorithm is more important, but to better understand, Java would do.

Comment: what platform?? C#? JAVA? C? C++?? which one??

Comment: planning to be language independent, just wanted to know the algo, but JAVA would be helpful

Comment: the main thing here is how do i fragment this string without affecting the signed digit

Comment: please check if my answer was helpful and let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this task is solved with lexical parser based on so-called [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

```
string s = "-2+-3+(4+5)";
List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
const int ST_NONE = 0, ST_MINUS = 1, ST_DIGITS = 2, ST_PUNCT = 3;
int j = 0; // token start
int st = ST_NONE; // state
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length(); ++i) {
    switch(s[i]) {
        case '0' .. '9':
            if (st != ST_NONE && st != ST_DIGITS) { // any prev token
                tokens.Add(s.SubStr(j, i - j)); // yield prev token
                j = i; // start of new token
            }
            st = ST_DIGITS; // note transition from ST_MINUS
            break;
        case '-': // special case since number can start with it
            if (st == ST_DIGITS) { // "4-" is definitely means "4 - .."
                tokens.Add(s.SubStr(j, i - j)); // yield prev number
                j = i, st = ST_PUNCT;
            }
            else if (st != ST_NONE) {
                tokens.Add(s.SubStr(j, i - j)); // yield prev token
                j = i, st = ST_MINUS;
            }
            else {
                j = i, st = ST_MINUS;
            }
            break;
        case '+': case '*': case '/': case '(': case ')':
            if (st != ST_NONE) { // any prev token
                tokens.Add(s.SubStr(j, i - j)); // yield prev token
                j = i;
            }
            st = ST_PUNCT;
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnexpectedCharacter();
    }
}
if (st != ST_NONE) { // any prev token
    tokens.Add(s.SubStr(j, i - j)); // yield prev token
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to note that a `-` is a binary operator only if it follows something that looks like a value, which in your case is either a digit or a `)`. So if you iterate over tokens (where a token is either an operator character or a series of digits), and just remember if the last token was a value (either digits or `)`), you can always decide whether or not to put a space after the current token. (And you can also catch some syntax errors.)